# Cytoscape cannot connect to apps.cytoscape.org

Tags: cytoscape

Sytstem and Environment : Windows 10, Cytoscape (3.8, also tried on 3.9)
java 11.0.15.1 2022-04-22 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.15.1+2-LTS-10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.15.1+2-LTS-10, mixed mode)

Clicked on Apps -> App Manager, see the message cannot connect to apps.cytoscape.org

I am not behind a proxy

[image: Cannot connect to apps.cytoscape.org]

Tried installing directly from app.cytoscape.org, but the install never finishes. See this message on cytoscape :

[image]

Downloaded JAR for Enrichment Pipeline and tried installing from file, but see the same error message :

[image]

What needs to be done to make the app installation work ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is definitely blocking your internet connection.  What I would suggest is to download the .jar file from the app store (quit Cytoscape, then go to the app store web site, and you'll see the download button).  Then you can use "Install from File..."